# I put my blog on a subpage, how do I get page title?

Tags: templates, page-template, blog, blog-page

I've got my blog setup on a subpage (not the front page) and I'm using the template file `home.php`, how can I get the contents from the page editor onto this subpage?

If I change the title of the page it changes in the nav menu, but how can I get this to display on the page? (i.e. as the `<h1>` header)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Untested, but try:

```
<?php
echo get_the_title( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
?>
```

But it's *somewhat* hackish. Really, the `page_on_front` and `page_for_posts` are intended to be nothing more than *placeholders* for the site front page and blog posts index page.

Comment: hackish, yes, but it works!

Comment: you should add some conditional check for the front page, just in case you decide later to move the blog back on the front :)

Comment: I don't think it's hackish as I'm sure that's what it was meant for.

Comment: This works too `<?php single_post_title(); ?>`. This is a bit awkward, but when you just need the title as string this works too.