# How can I have a static title on my blog page?

Tags: page-template, title, blog-page

My blog page is not my homepage. How can I add a title to the top of the page? i.e. "My Blog". Right now there is no title on the page. The title of the first post is at the top. (Sorry it's on my local machine or I'd provide a link and I'm too new to post an image.)

Things I've tried:

- Creating a "blog" template page. It didn't work because the blog
  always uses index.php. (Thanks to Rev. Voodoo for the [code](http://voodoopress.com/development-tip-how-to-know-what-template-is-being-used/) that
  helps you see which template is used.)
- There is a similar question on [stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/i-put-my-blog-on-a-subpage-how-do-i-get-page-title) but it's not really
  answered and I don't understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by top of the page?
you mean a browser title?
or just on the page as text? -- also what theme are you using?
quick answer for both. If you want some sort of static text to display. You can edit your theme's .php files. Like, index.php, page.php etc
to be found in wp-content/themes/yourtheme/... If you have basic html knowledge that shouldn't be a problem to locate where.
if it is the actual browser title look for the <title></title> tag, although you should be able to change that in your adminpages for most themes. Do give some more details on what exactly you are trying, or w

Answer (score 4):

the accepted answer in the [similar question on stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/i-put-my-blog-on-a-subpage-how-do-i-get-page-title) should work;

try to add this to a suitable location in index.php of your theme:

```
<?php if( is_home() && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) echo get_the_title( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It returned empty field. Just FYI.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/i-put-my-blog-on-a-subpage-how-do-i-get-page-title

Answer (score 1):

I discovered `<?php single_post_title(); ?>` that works for both **blog title** and for other **pages** without any modifications. :)

So you can use it on the top of the page, and also in the page.